# How do I combine several composed image sequences in one video?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image, video, output

I've rendered 3 image sequences, each one basically is a separate view layer, composed them in the compositor and now just want to get one video file from them.

In other words I want to get a video which is the same as the viewer node shows when I go backwards and forwards using the animation timeline. And cant find the magic (convert?) button to make such video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the compositor, add a Composite output node and feed it with the signal you want to export, and choose Render Animation from the render menu.

This node's output refers to the parameters you set in the properties panel.

Check if Compositor in enabled in Post procesing tab.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but render animation just sarts to rerender the animation from the begnnning, taking the usual time for it(as if it is being redndered for the first time). But I already have all the necessary image sequences and just want to combine what I already have.

Comment: I've never had ocasion to use it but isn't that what the Video Sequence editor is for?

Comment: Yes, I want the similar thing. You can import an image sequence to the Video editor and export it from it as a video(or vice versa) fast. But you cant composite in the VSE. And I need the same operation but in the compositor for different image sequences from different view layers, which(the sequences) have already been rendered  and composited in the Compositor and I want to find a way to export/convert the final result of the compositing without rerendering the whole animation one more time.

Comment: You have to delete Render Layers nodes and use Image sequence Node input instead.

Comment: Tnx for the answers. The deleteng render layers trick worked just the way I needed. I'm saved.